# What does the !! (double exclamation) operator do in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, operators

I found an sql code that looks like this. Removing the double exclamation statement (`!! ''`) returns the exact same results:

```
Select * from SomeTable a
where a.SOMEFIELD !! '' = 'SomeString'
```

What does the `!! ''` do?

Comment: Are you sure these are exclamation marks and not vertical bars (`||`)?

Comment: Yes, they are exclamation marks and Jens' answer is correct. I also did not know there are different forms of concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!!` operator is one form of concatenation. 
In your case it is used to enforce the convertion of a.SOMEFIELD to a character.

Comment: So was the code-owner just trying to make sure that the value compared with 'SomeString' is also a string?

Answer (score 1):

In DB2 LUW that is not possible:

```
db2 "create table SomeTable (SOMEFIELD int, col2 int)"
db2 "insert into SomeTable values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)"
db2 "select * from SomeTable a where a.SOMEFIELD !! '' = '1'"
SQL0007N  The character "!" following "om t2 t where t.col1" is not valid.
SQLSTATE=42601
```

Instead, what @mustaccio said is valid:

```
db2 "select * from t2 t where t.col1 || '' = '1'"

COL1        COL2
----------- -----------
          1           1

  1 record(s) selected.
```

However, the concatenation of null with something has a result of null; coalesce checks the first value if it is null, and then returns the second one:

```
db2 -x "values 'a' || 'b'"
ab
db2 -x "values NULL || ''"
-                                                                                                                                  

db2 -x "values NULL || 'b'"
-                                                                                                                                  

db2 -x "values coalesce(NULL, '')"

db2 -x "values coalesce(NULL, 'b')"
b
```